# Is it possible to destroy all GCP project components after working hours and recreate them the next day before work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I know that destroying the whole environment at night and recreating it in the morning is possible in other clouds but what about GCP? I am doing some bigdata calculations on composer and dataflow but I do not need them after working hours on my development environment and I would like to save money and automatically destroy all composers and dataflow jobs and then recreate them next day in the morning. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked into (researched) Terraform and Google Cloud Deployment Manager? There is also the CLI that you can use to create and delete resources.

Comment: Try to remove the billing account on the project. Normally, all the paid resource are stopped. But I don't know the behavior on the stored data (Disk, bigQuey and Storage)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using TerraForm for this, this will allow you to create your build and do your work during the day, and then you can use TerraForm destroy at the end of your day to delete resources. TerraForm works with Composer and Dataflow. Here is a [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/index.html) you can follow that will explain how TerraForm works.